# Repeater Control disable a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a repeater (named `list_user`) which contains fields (`id_user`, `name`, `mail`) and button `contact`. I want to perform a control that allows to disable the contact button for certain username
Here is my code

aspx:

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="list_user" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="list_user_ItemDataBound1">
          <HeaderTemplate>
              <table border="1" class="grid">
                  <thead>
                      <tr>
                          <th> Id user </th>  
                          <th> username </th>
                          <th> mail</th>
                          <th> Contact</th>                                                                    
                      </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                  </HeaderTemplate>
                  <ItemTemplate>
                 <tr>
                     <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="id_user" Text='<%# Eval("iduser")%>'></asp:Label></td>    
                     <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="username" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>' ></asp:Label></td> 
                     <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="mail" Text='<%# Eval("mail_adress")%>'></asp:Label></td>                                                
                    <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="contact" Text="contact_user" OnClick="contact_Click1"/></td>
                  </ItemTemplate>
                     <FooterTemplate>  
                      .....
```

Code Behind in c#

```
protected void list_user_ItemDataBound1(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        Label nom = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("username") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)e.Item.FindControl("contact") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button;               
        if (nom.Text == "alex")
        { btn.Enabled = true; }
        else
        { btn.Enabled = false; }
    }
```

but nothing happens to the display

Comment: what's problem...Have you bind the data while I used your code and taking class of user with your specified attribute.So it's working for me.It also disable other users-contact-button except "alex" specified..

Answer (score 0):

I used your above code it's working quite.You may have problem on **DataBind**. You look for valid databind.I have used your attribute in User class and made list of users then bind it to repeater control it's working fine.

**Aspx**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="list_user" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="list_user_ItemDataBound1">
      <HeaderTemplate>
          <table border="1" class="grid">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th> Id user </th>  
                      <th> username </th>
                      <th> mail</th>
                      <th> Contact</th>                                                                    
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              </HeaderTemplate>
              <ItemTemplate>
             <tr>
                 <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="id_user" Text='<%# Eval("iduser")%>'></asp:Label></td>    
                 <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="username" Text='<%# Eval("name")%>' ></asp:Label></td> 
                 <td><asp:Label runat="server" ID="mail" Text='<%# Eval("mail_adress")%>'></asp:Label></td>                                                
                <td><asp:Button runat="server" ID="contact" Text="contact_user" OnClick="contact_Click" /></td>
              </ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

**Code file**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<User> list = new List<User>();
        User u = new User();
        u.iduser = 0;
        u.name = "alex";
        u.uContact = "555399";
        u.mail_adress = "fdsfsfdsddsff@gmail.com";
        list.Add(u);
        for (int i = 1; i < 5;i++ )
        {
            u = new User();
            u.iduser = i;
            u.name = "alex "+i;
            u.uContact = "555399";
            u.mail_adress = "fsddfsdsdf@gmail.com";
            list.Add(u);
        }

        list_user.DataSource = list;
        list_user.DataBind();
    }
}
class User
{
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string mail_adress { get; set; }
    public string uContact { get; set; }
}
protected void list_user_ItemDataBound1(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {

        Label nom = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)e.Item.FindControl("username") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label;
        System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button btn = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)e.Item.FindControl("contact") as System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button;
        if (nom.Text == "alex")
        { btn.Enabled = true; }
        else
        { btn.Enabled = false; }

    }
}
protected void contact_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Add for click
}
```

**Output Result**

[image]

Comment: I put datasource and databind in the loading of the page, and the grid is filled by the data from the database but only list_user_ItemDataBound1 didn't work